# Error Onclick Gridview: cannot resolve symbol

Tags: android, gridview

I can't implement the method Onclick in my Gridview, this is my class and the error show cannot resolve symbol Toast? Any idea? if is necessary I can show the Adapter called CustomAdapter.

Edit: When I cliked there aren't any message

```
public class Tab3School extends Fragment {

    Context context;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, container, false);

        GridView gridview = (GridView)v.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        List<ItemNoticiasColegio> allItems = getAllItemObject();
        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), allItems);
        gridview.setAdapter(customAdapter);


        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                switch(position)
                {
                    case 0:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "FDSFASDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "FDSFASDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        break;

                    case 2:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "FDSFASDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    private List<ItemNoticiasColegio> getAllItemObject(){
        List<ItemNoticiasColegio> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(new ItemNoticiasColegio(R.drawable.alkor,"Dip It Low", "Christina Milian"));
        items.add(new ItemNoticiasColegio(R.drawable.alkor,"sdfasd", "gfgdfsfdg"));
        items.add(new ItemNoticiasColegio(R.drawable.alkor,"hola", "adios"));
        items.add(new ItemNoticiasColegio(R.drawable.padres,"marcos", "yo"));

        return items;
    }
}
```

I fix it adding this lines into my grid_layout

```
 android:focusable="false"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Comment: what return view refer to ?

Answer (score 1):

the error in your structure  , please review comment

```
public class Tab3School extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, container, false);

        GridView gridview = (GridView)v.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        List<ItemNoticiasColegio> allItems = getAllItemObject();
        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), allItems);
        gridview.setAdapter(customAdapter);

// move gridview before return view 
 gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return v;


       // return view; remove this mean no thing
    }







    private List<ItemNoticiasColegio> getAllItemObject(){
        List<ItemNoticiasColegio> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(new ItemNoticiasColegio(R.drawable.alkor,"Dip It Low", "Christina Milian"));
        items.add(new ItemNoticiasColegio(R.drawable.alkor,"sdfasd", "gfgdfsfdg"));
        items.add(new ItemNoticiasColegio(R.drawable.alkor,"hola", "adios"));
        items.add(new ItemNoticiasColegio(R.drawable.padres,"marcos", "yo"));





        return items;
    }

}
```

Comment: yep I fix It... the problem is the same cannot resolve symbol Toast